# Restricting Google Maps Places to Specific Countries using AutocompleteService()

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using `google.maps.places.AutocompleteService` how do you restrict the countries of the search (Canada and USA).  If you're using `AutoComplete` you can just add the country to the options, but that doesn't appear to be the case using the `AutocompleteService`.  I also found while looking through the docs `componentRestrictions`, but that also doesn't work.

How do you restrict the countries being searched using Google Places?

```
function initService(controlInput) {

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {

      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          console.log(status);
          return;
      }

      predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
          console.log(prediction);
      });
  };

  controlInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event, input) {
      service.getQueryPredictions({ 
        input: controlInput.value,
        //country: 'ca',  <--- doesn't work
        componentRestrictions: {
          country: 'ca' <--- also doesn't work
        }
      }, displaySuggestions);
  });
 }
```

Comment: try something like service.setComponentRestrictions({country: 'ca'})

Comment: Hi @UriBrecher, I actually tried that by attaching it to the service, but it throws `service.setComponentRestrictions is not a function`

Comment: my bad. setComponentRestrictions is a method of class AutoComplete not AutoCompleteService. When you say 'doesn't work' you mean that predictions are not restricted? or you don't get predictions at all?

Comment: Sorry @UriBrecher, meant the predictions are not restricted

Comment: OK, just making sure you understand that 'ca' means Canada and not California.

Answer (score 1):

Try following this guide from [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=cs#RegionCodes):

> In a geocoding response, the Google Maps Geocoding API can return address results restricted to a specific area. The restriction is specified using the components filter. A filter consists of a list of component:value pairs separated by a pipe (|). Only the results that match all the filters will be returned. Filter values support the same methods of spelling correction and partial matching as other geocoding requests. If a geocoding result is a partial match for a component filter it will contain a partial_match field in the response.
>
> The components that can be filtered include:
>
> - route matches long or short name of a route.
> - locality matches against both locality and sublocality types.
> - administrative_area matches all the administrative_area levels.
> - postal_code matches postal_code and postal_code_prefix.
> - country matches a country name or a two letter [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) country code.
>
> ***Note***: Each address component can only be specified either in the address parameter or as a component filter, but not both. Doing so may result in `ZERO_RESULTS`.
>
> A geocode for "Santa Cruz" with `components=country:ES` will return Santa Cruz de Tenerife in Canary Islands, Spain. Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=country:ES&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Also here [Restrict the search to a specific country](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area) on how it's implementation about restricting search and follow the ISO 3166-1(two letter country code). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AutocompleteService.getQueryPredictions method which does not accepts componentRestrictions option. It is valid for AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions method. See documentation:

AutocompleteService:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService

AutocompletionRequest:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest

QueryAutocompletionRequest:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest

Answer (score 0):

I've used a country select option to set the value of autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions.

The autcomplete will be restricted to searching from that country. 
Please excuse the formatting as I've just dumped it in here.

```
    function setAutocompleteCountry() {
    var country = document.getElementById('id_countryselect').value;
    if (country === 'ALL') {
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
    } else {
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
    }
}

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    ------> Rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with getPlacesPredicitions after you initiate AutocompleteServices. You can include it in the request object like so:

```
 const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
 let request = {
     input: val,                    
     componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
 };
 service.getPlacePredictions(request, (predictions, status) => {
    this.addresses = predictions
   //each predicition is one address
 });
```